# How do I find the side measures of a triangle, only given the angles and no other information?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, angle

I was doing my Geometry EOC review which led me to a question asking me to "List the sides of the triangle in order from SHORTEST to LONGEST". This made me confused because the only information given was three angles, the measure of angles A(59), B(77), and C(44). How should I attempt to solve a problem like this? Thanks.

Image below ↓

[Triangle illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRYvF.png)

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: You can't find the lengths precisely, since the triangle may simply be scaled without changing the angles. However, you can for this problem just assume one side length (e.g. $AB=1$), then compute the others.

Comment: Euclid I-19: http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/propI19.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so you cannot give an exact number as that triangle can be infinitely big or infinitely small and the angles are preserved. Instead you can compare the ratio of the sides by looking at the angles opposite. The bigger the angle opposite, the longer the side.
So you can simply say AC is the longest side, then BC, and so on.

If you need to get an actual ratio of one side to the other, you can assume one side equals ‘x’, then use the cosine rule and/or the sine rule to complete the other lengths in terms of x. However given the angles involved these won’t be nice neat numbers and so believe the first part is what you’re looking for.

Comment: "The bigger the angle opposite, the longer the side." This is only true if all the angles are acute. The sine rule directly gives the proportions of the sides - the sides are proportional to the sine of the opposite angle - and the sine function is only monotone increasing up to 90 degrees.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis so are you saying that in an obtuse angled triangle, the side opposite to the obtuse angle is not the largest?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis  According to the cosine rule, the side length depends inversely on the $\cos$ of the angle opposite to it and since the $\cos$ function is decreasing in the first two quadrants...so we get the desired theorem or result (larger the angle opposite, larger the side)

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad You're right. Although the side lengths are proportional to the sines of the opposite angle, and the sine function is not increasing beyond 90 degrees, the fact that the angles sum to 180 means it doesn't matter. The angle sizes are ordered the same as their sines.

Comment: Thank you so much, this really helped! (especially since my work is due soon)